# Rcpp multiple functions in a file and no matching function

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to run the function `weights` below in R. Functions `mN` and `PsiN` below work individually, and I do not need to export them into R (i.e. their only purpose is to keep the function weights looking neater).

For some reason, only `mN` gives me the error "no matching function call" within the function `weights`. Any idea as to why?

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

arma::vec mN(double kappa, double ni, arma::vec m, arma::vec C) {
  arma::vec mN; 
  double kappaN;
  kappaN = kappa + ni;
  mN = (kappa/kappaN) * m + (ni/kappaN) * C;
  return mN; 
}
arma::mat PsiN(double ni, double kappa, double kappaN,
               arma::mat y, arma::vec indic, arma::vec C, arma::vec m,
               arma::mat Psi) { 
  double r = indic.n_elem;
  double p = y.n_cols; 
  double n = y.n_rows;
  arma::mat S(p, p); 
  arma::mat PN(p, p); 
  if (r == 1) {
    PN = Psi + kappa*ni/kappaN * ( (C - m ) * (C - m).t() ); 
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      S += y.row(i).t() * y.row(i);
    }
    PN = Psi + S + kappa*ni/kappaN * ( (C - m ) * (C - m).t() ) ;  
  }
  return PN;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::vec weights(int alpha, int v, int kappa, int m,
                  arma::vec nj, arma::mat x, arma::mat Psi, 
               List C, List indic) {
  int p = x.n_cols;
  int n = x.n_rows;
  int kappaN;
  int vN; 
  int crp; 
  arma::vec Q; 
  arma::vec mu;
  arma::mat Sigma;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    kappaN = kappa + nj[i];
    vN     = v + nj[i] - p + 1;
    Sigma  = PsiN(nj[i], kappa, kappaN, x, indic[i], C[i], m, Psi);
    Sigma  = Sigma*(kappaN + 1)/(kappaN*(vN - p + 1));
    mu     = mN(kappa, kappaN, nj[i], m, C[i]); 
    crp    = log(nj[i]) - log(n + alpha - 1);
    Q[i]   = (crp - lgamma((vN + p)/2) - lgamma(vN/2) - p/2*(log(vN) + log(
      datum::pi)) - 1/2*log_det(Sigma) - (vN + p)/2 * (log(1 + 1/v*(x - mu).t()*Sigma.i()*(x-mu)))) ;
  }

 return Q;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function signature for `mN` is

```
arma::vec mN(double, double, arma::vec, arma::vec)
```

But you call it as

```
mu     = mN(kappa, kappaN, nj[i], m, C[i]);
```

where `kappa` is `int`, `kappaN` is `int`, `nj[i]` is `double`, `m` is `int` and `C` is a `List` of `SEXP`s.

Note that unlike R, you can't in general mix doubles and ints in C++ with abandon. In particular, I'll also point out that declarations like

```
double r = indic.n_elem;
double p = y.n_cols; 
double n = y.n_rows;
```

should all be `int`s or `unsigned int`s.

Answer (score 3):

The function signatures in the definition:

```
arma::vec mN(double kappa, double ni, arma::vec m, arma::vec C)
```

does not match its usage:

```
mu     = mN(kappa, kappaN, nj[i], m, C[i]);
```

You have to decide whether the function needs 4 or 5 arguments.

Comment: @statkat You are welcome. Consider upcoming/accepting the answer, but also look at Hong Ooi's answer, which contains some valuable advice.